# Gmap API results differents from website

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, zero, google-geocoder

I'm using Gmap to Geocode some address in my application.
It's working very well except for one address : 3311 ESPERANZA CROSSING, Austin, United States.

When I try via the Gmap client or via the server-side request, I have the result ZERO_RESULTS :

```
{   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

But when a search the same address on gmap ( [http://maps.google.fr/maps?q=3311+ESPERANZA+CROSSING,+Austin,+United+States](http://maps.google.fr/maps?q=3311%20ESPERANZA%20CROSSING,%20Austin,%20United%20States) ), there is results.

How is this possible ?

Thank you for helping me.

Below the link use for the server-side request : 
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3311+ESPERANZA+CROSSING,+Austin,+United+States&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3311%20ESPERANZA%20CROSSING,%20Austin,%20United%20States&sensor=false)

And below the client-side request :

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
if (geocoder) {
        // Create the complete adress                               
    var complete_address = '3311 ESPERANZA CROSSING, Austin, United States';

    // Start request
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': complete_address }, function (gmap_results, status) {
            console.log( gmap_results ); 
            console.log( status );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result in Google Maps is a Places result, not from the Geocoder.